# to_sql() error querying sqlite_master table when writing to MySQL

Tags: pandas, mysql-python, pandas-to-sql

I have a question about how to save a dataframe to my local mysql.

```
import MySQLdb
import pandas as pd
conn=MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user='root',passwd="matt123",db="ada")
df=pd.DataFrame(['A','B'],columns=['new_tablecol'])
df.to_sql(name='new_table',con=conn,if_exists='append')
```

after typing this code , it says

```
pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;': not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

I am confused about this.I can query and create table . but I can't save this dataframe.

Answer (score 33):

Your way is not supported anymore.

> **con :** SQLAlchemy engine or DBAPI2 connection (legacy mode)
>
> Using SQLAlchemy makes it possible to use any DB supported by that
>   library. If a DBAPI2 object, only sqlite3 is supported.
>
> **flavor :** ‘sqlite’, default None
>
> Deprecated since version 0.19.0: ‘sqlite’ is the only supported option
>   if SQLAlchemy is not used.

[pandas.DataFrame.to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)

Try this?

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd


engine = create_engine("mysql://root:matt123@localhost/ada")
con = engine.connect()
df = pd.DataFrame(['A','B'],columns=['new_tablecol'])
df.to_sql(name='new_table',con=con,if_exists='append')
con.close()
```

Syntax is:

```
engine = create_engine("mysql://USER:PASSWORD@HOST/DATABASE")
```

More information about `sqlalchemy` can be found [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html)