# uploading dataframe to an existing table in sql server

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that I want to upload to a SQL Server database.

I have been looking at the pandas [to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) method but I can't seem to get it to work.

My dataframe is say 500 rows with 3 columns

```
column name      data type
dateLg           datetime
temperature      float64
city             object
```

And so my SQL table is called tblCityTemperature

```
  column name          data type
  DateLeg              datetime
  Temp                 float
  CC                   nvarchar(20)
```

Is there a way of mapping the columns in a dataframe to my sql table?

I tried the following where tblColNames is the three names in my sql table.

```
df.to_sql("tblPrices", cnxn, index_label=tblColNames)
```

I get the error message below which doesn't really make sense to me

> ValueError: Length of 'index_label' should match number of levels, which is 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your columns before `to_sql`

```
df.columns=['DateLeg','Temp','CC']
```

Then you just need

```
df.to_sql("tblPrices", cnxn, if_exists ='append')
```

Comment: Thanks, does it matter if the columns are in a different order to the sql they are being appended to? I'm getting this error... DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;': ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'sqlite_master'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW); [42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")

Comment: I am to get data out of the sql table just fine

Comment: @mHelpMe if the name same it is ok , and you may need adding index=False as well since you append to an exist table

Comment: @mHelpMe also it is better check the way mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43136121/questions-about-pandas-to-sql, change the way you are using

Comment: thanks just trying that now... still having database issues. Will keep plugging away at it